# Missing data from Parse to UIPickerView in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6, uipickerview

[image: In this picture, there're many data are still missing in the picker view]

I've pass the data from the Parse which the class name called 'Timetable' and the data will be get from the column name called 'Intake'. The picker view is able to get the data from it, however there're still a lot of data are still missing which not showing in the picker view. Does anyone know what problem is this?

***I've pointed the uipickerview delegate and datasource to self

The code will be shown below...

```
var pickerString:NSMutableArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Timetable")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
            {
                (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil
                {
                    for object in objects! as [AnyObject]
                    {
                        if !self.pickerString.containsObject(object["Intake"] as! String) {
                            self.pickerString.addObject(object["Intake"] as! String)
                            //to avoid the duplication of the same data in picker view
                        }
                    }
                    self.pvIntakeCode.reloadAllComponents()
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error!, error!.userInfo!)
                }
        }
```

And these is the data source and delegates function of picker view will shown below...

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    // returns the # of rows in each component..
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.pickerString.count
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
    {
        return self.pickerString[row] as! String
    }
```

Comment: Please, do not post a screenshot of code.  Instead, copy+paste the code as text into the question.

Comment: Okay @Anna I will try to edit now. Sorry

Comment: what response you got from println() ?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin if i put println on the self.pickerString.count and self.pickerString[row]...the value will be so weird.
'0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
7
7
7
AFCF1401
AFCF1404
AFCF1401
AFCF1404
AFCF1408
AFCF1410
AFCF1401'

**without scrolling the pickerview

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin just wondering why it keep loops from the beginning everytime a next new value is come out

Comment: can you show your actual data inside your parse?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin I pass the json file for you, you try to import it to Parse and look for the column called "Intake"...I've give you the download link for that json file
http://1drv.ms/1KcdTB2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code to maximise the number of object into the array from Parse.

```
var limit:NSInteger = 1000
        var skip:NSInteger = 0
        query.limit = limit
        query.skip = skip
```